# Getting Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index id when removing frequent word from tweets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying sentiment analysis from the twitter post. I am new to sentiment analysis.In text preprocessing phase, I have encountered a problem to remove frequent words from twits. i want to remove most frequent words from twits so I have counted most frequent terms in twit by

```
freq=pd.Series(''.join(traindata['tweet']).split()).value_counts()[:10]
```

then i have converted the freq series into list

```
freq=list(freq.index)
```

Up to this point, my result is showing[image]

For filtering my twitter_word  column by removing frequently used words. I have used below code

```
traindata['tweet']=traindata.apply(lambda x:" ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in freq))
```

and I have got below error

**File "C:\Users\codemen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index id')**

kindly help me to figure out the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need specify column for `apply`, else looping all columns of `DataFrame`:

```
f = lambda x:" ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in freq)
traindata['tweet'] = traindata['tweet'].apply(f)
```